# More than one react app in .net core application

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I have created a server-side rendering react app using .net core (which is already given by .net core).
I want to have more than one react app inside .net core app.
I didn't get any related links to it.
Please help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use webpack to make multiple react builds from different react projects. Then when you use SSR in your .net core controllers, you can set different views using multiple view layouts or just views, each targeting a different react app. - Of course you'll need to dig deeper since what you are asking is a lot of setup and coding but this is one possible solution.

1. Write your react apps / if you are using create-react-app, use the 'eject' feature to get the hidden files so you can expand on them.
2. Use one Webpack config to make separate builds
3. Make multiple controllers with SSR or one that selectively issues view pages based on your use case - SPA Services SSR is gone in .net core 5, you can still use core 3.1 or there are many libs in the works and require some reworking your startup setup and controller
4. Add View pages or Razor pages targeting the react app

This is not the only way but will get you going with the least amount of fuss.

Webpack is the key here, hope this helps you in the right direction.